# Why is id() function in migration instead of bigIncrements() by default in a migration file?

Tags: php, laravel, migration, database-migration

I've been watching a tutorial on Laravel and there is $table->bigIncrements("id") in a migration file, but when I open the same file there is $table->id() function.

Questions:

1. **Was there any update in which bigIncrements was replaced by id()?** I've been searching the net for a while but haven't found anything about it.
2. **Do these functions do the same? Is there any difference between them?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are in doubt like that, always go to the source of truth... In this case it is open source, so go to GitHub and look for yourself... This is what all devs do...

So, if you look at [Laravel 6.x](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/ecf460a874e5943c1063ef9585bc7491ead15b0a/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php#L17), they used `bigIncrements`, but if you look on [Laravel 7.x+](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/3923e7f7c40368a5e78c1a33610191be8ad91e3b/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php#L17), you will see they use `id` now...

More info on the [Framework source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/cada3d21c7f127ba01bb949b2fa045b7faaedbca/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L555-L564)...

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `id()` uses a default name which is `id`, and most of the time, you don't need to type it, and therefore it helps you develop faster.

> The id method is an alias of the bigIncrements

[Laravel - migrations - id()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#column-method-id)

> The bigIncrements method creates an auto-incrementing UNSIGNED BIGINT (primary key) equivalent column:

[Laravel - migrations - bigIncrements()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#column-method-bigIncrements)